# How do I sum until it meets a criteria?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following data set for an user. I want to merge the False flag rows to the latest True row.

initial set:

```
user    input_date  starting_balance deposit flag
user1   2020-08-20         100           20   TRUE
user1   2020-08-21         200            0   TRUE
user1   2020-08-23         null         200   FALSE
user1   2020-08-24         300          130   TRUE
user1   2020-08-25         400          0     TRUE
```

output:

```
user    input_date  starting_balance deposit flag
user1   2020-08-20         100           20   TRUE
user1   2020-08-21         200            0   TRUE
user1   2020-08-24         300          330   TRUE
user1   2020-08-25         400          0     TRUE
```

sql to recreate data:

```
select 'user1' as user, '2020-08-20' as input_date, 100 as starting_balance, 20 as deposit, true as flag
union all
select 'user1', '2020-08-21', 200, 0, true
union all
select 'user1', '2020-08-23', null, 200, false
union all
select 'user1', '2020-08-24', 300, 130, true
union all
select 'user1', '2020-08-25', 400, 0, true;
```

Comment: But your expected result tells a different story. It didn't merge to the latest true row. Do you mean the next `true` row right after the `false` row ....and what happens if you have consecutive `false` rows.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS as SQL maintains different dialects across databases.

Comment: consecutive false rows will merge with first true down the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an aggregation problem.  You can use a cumulative sum to assign groups.  And then aggregate.  The group is the number of "trues" up to each row.  So:

```
select user, max(input_date), sum(starting_balance),
       sum(deposit), true as flag
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when flag then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user order by input_date desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by user, grp
order by user, input_date;
```